# Kotlin interface with generics and Dagger

Tags: generics, kotlin, dagger-2

I have an interface defined where I have a generic type with the following

```
interface ActivityService<T> {
  fun getActivities(context: Context, listener: GetActivitiesListener<T>)
  fun addActivity(activity: T, context: Context, listener: AddActivityListener)
}
```

And is implemented with

```
class AwsActivityService : ActivityService<Activity> {

override fun addActivity(activity: Activity, context: Context, listener: AddActivityListener) {
    AddActivityAsyncTask(activity, context, object : AddActivityAsyncTask.ActivityTaskListener {
        override fun onTaskComplete(result: Boolean) {
            listener.onTaskComplete(result)
        }
    }).execute()
}

override fun getActivities(context: Context, listener: GetActivitiesListener<Activity>) {
    GetActivitiesAsyncTask(context, object : GetActivitiesAsyncTask.ActivityTaskListener {
        override fun onTaskComplete(activityList: List<Activity>) {
            return listener.onTaskComplete(activityList)
        }
    }).execute()
}
```

}

How do you then define the generics for the module within Dagger when instantiating AwsActivityService?

```
@Module
class ActivitiesModule() {

    @Provides
    @Inject
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideActivitiesModule(): ActivityService {
        return AwsActivityService()
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but wouldn't you define it on the return type of provideActivitiesModule?
`internal fun provideActivitiesModule(): ActivityService<Activity>`

Comment: That does work but I'm trying to make this generic so that there is a potential for other services in the future e.g. GoogleActivityService that uses a different type of Activity.

Comment: This makes no sense, and can be compared to returning Object/Any from your `@Provides` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could parhaps use a [factory pattern](https://chercher.tech/kotlin/factory-design-pattern-kotlin) to provide multiple classes based on type.

```
@Module
class ActivitiesModuleFactory() {

    @Provides
    @Inject
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideActivitiesModuleFactory(): ActivityServiceFactory {
        return ActivityServiceFactory()
    }
}
```

```
class ActivityServiceFactory {

  inline fun <reified T: Any> getActivities(context: Context, listener: GetActivitiesListener<T>) =
    when(T::class) {
      GoogleActivity::class -> google.getActivities(context, listener as GetActivitiesListener<GoogleActivity>)
      AwsActivity::class -> aws.getActivities(context, listener as GetActivitiesListener<AwsActivity>)
      else -> //throw error or use default listener here
    }

  fun addActivity(activity: any, context: Context, listener: AddActivityListener)=
    when(activity) {
      is GoogleActivity -> google.addActivity(activity, context, listener)
      is AwsActivity -> aws.addActivity(activity, context, listener)
      else -> //throw error or use default listener here
    }

  companion object { 
    val aws = AwsActivityService()
    val google = GoogleActivityService()
  }
}
```

```
GoogleActivityService : ActivityService<GoogleActivity> {
    override fun addActivity(activity: GoogleActivity, context: Context, listener: AddActivityListener) {
      AddActivityAsyncTask(activity, context, object : AddActivityAsyncTask.ActivityTaskListener {
        override fun onTaskComplete(result: Boolean) {
          listener.onTaskComplete(result)
        }
    }).execute()
    }

    override fun getActivities(context: Context, listener: GetActivitiesListener<GoogleActivity>) {
      GetActivitiesAsyncTask(context, object : GetActivitiesAsyncTask.ActivityTaskListener {
        override fun onTaskComplete(activityList: List<GoogleActivity>) {
          return listener.onTaskComplete(activityList)
        }
    }).execute()
 }
```

The basic idea it to create a factory with a companion object containing instances of each type you need. This factory has an interface that accepts any type and then uses a when statement with type checking to call the correct activity service. Since companion objects are bound to the class there is only one of each ActivityService.

Comment: There is an issue to this solution when it comes to `is GetActivitiesListener<GoogleActivity>` It looks like type erassure prevents this type checking so you would need to pass a class type as part of the signature or replace the single method with a method for each type.

Comment: I updated the answer to correct for the issue with generics.